# AppMutex doesn't work on Inno Setup

Tags: c#, mutex, inno-setup

Seems that `AppMutex` directive doesn't work for my installation script.
I follow this articles: http://www.jmedved.com/2012/06/mutex-for-innosetup/

This is my C# code of my application:

```
private static string appGuid = "Loader";
...
bool createdNew;
var mutexSec = new MutexSecurity();
mutexSec.AddAccessRule(
    new MutexAccessRule(
        new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null),
        MutexRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

using (var setupMutex = new Mutex(false, @"Global\"+appGuid, out createdNew, mutexSec))
{
    if (!createdNew)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(
             "Application already running.", "Loader", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
             MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Loader(args));
}
```

In Inno Setup script i just have:

```
AppMutex=Loader
```

However the installer could run also if the application is running.

I also tried to check if there really was the mutex, so with process explorer I looked for application handlers and i get this:

```
AppMutex=Loader

Mutant    \BaseNamedObjects\Loader
```

What I miss?

Comment: I'd say you're missing the `Global\ ` scope prefix in your `AppMutex` directive value. I doubt that without that prefix would mutexes be created in the global namespace. So I would rather use `AppMutex=Global\Loader`.

Comment: This is the answer! please answer so I can accept your solution. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you've created mutex in the `Global\` namespace in your application, you should explicitly do the same also for the [`AppMutex`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appmutex) mutex name in your Inno Setup script, since mutex objects are not created in global namespace if you omit namespace prefix. So using this script line should fix your problem:

```
[Setup]
AppMutex=Global\Loader
```

Answer (score 0):

In Inno Setup's [Setup] section:

```
AppMutex=[mutex name]
```

In Class section of application's main form (outside of form_Load):

```
Dim mutex As New System.Threading.Mutex(False, "[mutex name]")
```

(note this is in vb, not c#)